# Scala + Playframework 2.3.X importing dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework

I am having problems importing two dependencies here is the import

```
import io.GooglePlayClient
import io.GooglePlayError
```

and I get this error

> object GooglePlayError is not a member of package akka.io
>
> [error] import io.GooglePlayError
>
> object GooglePlayClient is not a member of package akka.io
>
> [error] import io.GooglePlayClient

It seems it is prefixing the package where I am trying to import (akka) to this imports, and the is not able to import.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `akka.io` imported in scope. So, akka.io.GooglePlayError is tried. Instead use `import _root_.io.GooglePlayError`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not sure why this is happening, is because akka and io are custom packages? because in controllers I do not have the same problem. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you are getting this error. But from the error that you have shown, it seems that you have already imported `akka.io`. So `io.GooglePlayError` is inferred as  `akka.io.GooglePlayError`. The `_root_` package is the outermost package and thats why its possible to use `_root_.io.GooglePlayError`.

Comment: thank you for your answer and for the last comment, now I understand where it was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to import using the fully qualified name of the dependencies if available, that is

```
import com.yourcompany.io.GooglePlayClient
import com.yourcompany.io.GooglePlayError
```

If the `io` package is really a root package, you could consider refactoring your package structure to something like the above.